# how to use file.rename to rename from an edited file list in R

Tags: r, file, rename

I am remming some files. First I create a list.

```
files_list<-list.files()
```

Now I edit the list of files so I can manually arrange them in any order I want.

```
new_files_list<-edit(files_list)
```

Using the file.rename function I am able to rename the files numerically.
How can I modify the command below so it uses the file order I manually set in the above command?

```
file.rename(from = list.files(pattern="file*"), paste0(stem_file_name,numeric_renaming, ".abc"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will rename all files in the folder by numerate them. 
Be carfull with this, you can produce a lot of disorder in your system when you don't change the working directory with `setwd()`.

```
setwd("/home/spazieren/playground")
files_list<-list.files()
new_files_list <- edit(files_list)
file.rename(from = files_list, to=new_files_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my main question is to edit the list of files manually in new_files_list<-edit(files_list), then somehow use that new list in the file.rename function

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your point. But you can use it last with your line